# Static MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, static, mediaelement

I have two window (win1 and win2).
In the win1.xaml I have the mediaelement and I try to call it from the win2 C# source, which force me to have a static mediaelement.

So I use binding for filling the source, but to call method as mediaelement.play() how can I do that, because the mediaelement is declared in the xaml and is not static?

Thanks for your help.

win1.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="630" Height="460" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="626"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="24*"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Height="440" Width="620" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,2,-12">
        <StackPanel Height="350" Width="587" Background="White" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <!-- MediaElement -->
            <MediaElement Margin="10,11,10,0" Name="MediaElement1" Source="{Binding MediaElement1Source, Source={x:Static bindableSettings:BindingManager.Instance}}"
             Width="565" Height="330" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Close" Stretch="Fill" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

win1.xaml.cs
MediaElement init and some other stuff

win2.xaml
Just a button to call the function

win2.xaml.cs

`namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class win2 : Window
    {
        public win2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }`

```
    public static void MediaElement1_Play()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MediaElement1_Play Called");
        win1.MediaElement1.Play();
        MessageBox.Show("MediaElement1_Play Exited");

        // Other statics stuff
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you show some code?

Answer (score 0):

I tried using a static mediaelement as well (defining it as static class member in the code behind). It compiled OK, but no sound would play. I'm not sure why--maybe some of you experts out there would understand? I gave up on the static idea and went back to including it in the code for each Window. (Not ideal because I have a block of code to manipulate it--in my case playing notification sounds--and I have that code duplicated now in each window.) If anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear it.